# How Can I Show Or Hide Only A Part Of My Table To Guest Users In Laravel?

Tags: laravel, roles, user-roles, laravel-authentication

I Have A Page That Shows a Table , I want to hide only 1 Columns Of My table and only show to Admin User role .

But I want to show other columns to my guest users that have not logged in my site.
when i do with this code :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
...
</td>
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
<td>
only Admins Can See This Column
</td>
@endif
<td>
...
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It Hide All of page and redirect to login and show only to admin users.

But I need to show all my tables without that column to guset users that not logged in, How should i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found The solution :::
We can hide for guest and show to our role users by this code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        ...
        </td>
        @if(Auth()->check() and Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        <td>
            only Admins Can See This Column
        </td>
        @endif
        <td>
           ...
        </td>
        ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@guest` blade's directive.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        ...
        </td>
        @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        <td>
            only Admins Can See This Column
        </td>
        @endif
        @guest
        <td>
           This is only for guest!
        </td>
        @endguest
        ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your codes shows me this error : `Call to a member function isAdmin() on null` ,I want to hide from **not logged in users** and `@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())` is for when a user logged in not guests

Comment: this table is on my first page of my site and i want to hide one column of that for users that not logged in

Comment: I thought that you had already done isAdmin function. Then, if you want roles/permission you can use package like [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: i want to separate columns view for my guest users that not logged and signed up on my site , for users we can use the codes like you said , the laravel permission does't have role for guests users

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the admin user and show rest of the users you can follow these steps.

In your Controller:-

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
        $user = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id)->get();
    } else {
        $user = User::all();
    }
    return view('admin.users.index', compact('user'));
}
```

In your blade file:-

```html
@foreach($user as $users)
    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
        <tr>
            <td>{{$users->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$users->password}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $users->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <form action="{{ route('users.destroy', $users->id)}}" method="post" style="display: inline-block">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```